# Is there a way to collect web data selectively in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, na, rvest

I am trying to scrape the data from the German Rakuten site. The Rakuten company is the Japanese based worldwide known enterprise selling all kinds of stuff over the Internet. The problem is they are employing different market strategies for different countries. For example, in the US one cannot get to the products prior to paying the so called subscribtion fee. In Germany it is different, there one can have the immediate access to the products and prices. Therefore it seems the links of Rakuten are geotagged, i.e., one cannot see the content if logging in from another destination. This preamble is important for everyone trying to follow my steps and getting connection errors.
OK, so that said, I want to read the data and to save it to the dataframe.

Here's my initial code:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)     

rakuten <- "https://www.rakuten.de/suchen/kitchenAid?category=0"
ra_html <- read_html(rakuten)

title <- html_nodes(ra_html, ".vw-productCard .name") 
price <- html_nodes(ra_html, ".vw-productCard .price .actual")
discount <- html_nodes(ra_html, ".vw-productCard .thumb .discount .text")
```

As one can see, I want to scrape the product descriptions (title object), the price (price object) and the discount availability (discount object) if any. There are always descriptions and prices given for every product they sell (I am looking at the KitchenAid prices) but *discounts happen really rarely*.

Then I parse the data:

```
urlrakuten <- sprintf("https://www.rakuten.de/suchen/kitchenAid?category=0", 1:10)

#define empty data frame to store all data
alllistings <- data.frame()

for (i in urlrakuten){
  
  print(i)
  #read the page just once
  page <- read_html(i)
      
  # parse titles
 title <- page%>%html_nodes('.vw-productCard .name') %>% html_text()
 
  # parse prices
  price <- page %>% html_nodes('.vw-productCard .price .actual') %>% html_text()
  
  # parse discounts
  discount <- page %>% html_nodes('.vw-productCard .thumb .discount .text') %>%  html_text()

  #create temporary dataframe to store data from this loop
  tempdf <- data.frame(title, price, discount) 
  
  #combine temp with all data
  alllistings <- rbind(alllistings, tempdf)
}
```

It works exceptionally well with the first two objects, but not with the last one (discounts). There are only four discounts on the first page and R scrapes all of them and then fills the rest of the rows with repetitions of these four values, see my output:

[image: output]

I am definitely missing something but I have no idea how to fix it. I would like to have the same output with the third column values organized to the rows they belong and the rest just filled with NAs.

Comment: Does this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540089/how-to-get-rid-of-the-error-while-scraping-web-in-r/63540792#63540792

Comment: @ Dave2e Thanks for your quick reply, Dave. No, this rearrangement gives me unfortunately only three rows (observations) of NAs. I included the fourth column with urls as in your code, the urls are nicely collected and presented. I think my implementation of the wrapping here is somehow incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the strategy of this question: [How to get rid of the error while scraping web in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540089/how-to-get-rid-of-the-error-while-scraping-web-in-r/63540792#63540792).  Since not every product has a discount using the `html_nodes()` function will cause the issues you are seeing since it only  returns the found nodes.
Thus the solution is to generate a vector all of the product's parent nodes and then parse each of parent node with `html_node()`.  The `html_node()` function will always return a value even if it is just NA.

Also note: I am using the `lapply` function to return a list of dataframes (one for each page) and binding them together at the same time.  This is a significant performance improvement over the incremental approach from binding within a loop.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

readpage <- function(url){
   #read the page once
   page <-read_html(url)
   
   #parse out the parent nodes (the product)
   products <- page %>% html_nodes( "li.vw-productCard")
   
   #Now extract one piece of imformation per parent
   #title
   title <- products%>%html_node('.name') %>% html_text() 
   
   # parse prices
   price <- products %>% html_node('.price .actual') %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
  
   # parse discounts (html_node will return NA if no discount is available)
   discount <- products %>% html_node('.thumb .discount .text') %>%  html_text()
   
   #return a tibble/data,frame
   tibble(title, price, discount, url)
}

listofurls <- paste0("https://www.rakuten.de/suchen/kitchenAid?category=0&page=", 1:10)

dfs <- lapply(listofurls, function(url){ readpage(url)})
finalanswer <- bind_rows(dfs)
```

Comment: @ Dave2e Thanks for your detailed explanation and working program, Dave. Works like a charm, outstanding. My deepest appreciation and respect. I think my node definition was incorrect as well. Could you suggest me a program / approach to pinpoint the right nodes for the right entities.

Comment: @kshtwork, Some people use a tool called "selector-gadget" but I prefer to use the developer tools from my browser to examine the structure.  This will also help if it is a dynamic Java-scripted page.  Most people make the mistake of jumping directly to gathering all of the details first.  It is better to start at a higher level, a parent node common to the individual details.  In this case, start with the product node and then extract the details from each product.  It is subtle difference but it is important for success. Hope this helped.

Comment: @ Dave2e Yes, that gave me a broader view of the methods people use. Again, thanks a lot.