# Within a function, return NA or 0 if xpath is not to found

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, dplyr, rvest

Within a function, I need to return "NA" or better "0" for an xpath item that is NOT (!) on thapge. On most pages I scrape from the list the xpath item exists, but on some not. If it doesn't exists, the return vector becomes asymmetrical and connot be further combined.

```
return_data <- function(url) {
  page <- url %>% read_html 
  tibble(YealyRevenue = page %>%
           html_nodes(xpath = '//div[contains(h4, "YealyRevenue")]') %>%
           html_text(trim = TRUE) %>%
           parse_number(), 
         Cashflow = page %>% 
           html_nodes(xpath = '//div[contains(h4, "Cashflow:")]') %>% 
           html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% 
           parse_number(), 
         Spendings =  page %>% 
           html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="Spendings"]/a' ) %>% 
           html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% 
           parse_number(), 
         Return = page %>% 
           html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="Return"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/h1') %>%
           html_text(trim = TRUE))
}
```

The last item is the one which is not always existent on all the pages I scrape.

```
Return = page %>% 
           html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="Return"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/h1') %>%
           html_text(trim = TRUE)
```

So for this, I would need something like

"If this xpath is not found, please return "0"

Thanks for any leads!

Comment: You can wrap with `tryCatch` to do this

Comment: I am not familiar with tryCatch. can you explain?

Comment: Are you getting any errors when there are no xpath or is it returning silently.  `tryCatch` works by capturing that error and then we return a custom value for those cases

Comment: Yes, my entire script stops as the data from the funcition is normally collected and merged into a combined vector with cbind. If the respective xpath is not on the page, the vectors have different lenghts and thus cannot be combined. 
Which is why I need a "NA" or "0" return to have the same length in all 4 scraped items.

Comment: can you try the solution posted below.  I havent' tested it, but I assume it to work

Comment: You need to scrape the parent node and then use `html_node()` - no "s" to scrape the desired information.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540089/how-to-get-rid-of-the-error-while-scraping-web-in-r/63540792#63540792

Answer (score 0):

We could wrap the chain with a `tryCatch` and specify the `return` value when there is an `error`.  It is also possible to add more `return` values in case there are `warning`

```
return_data <- function(url) {
  page <- url %>% read_html 
  YealyRevenue <- page %>%
           html_nodes(xpath = '//div[contains(h4, "YealyRevenue")]') %>%
           html_text(trim = TRUE) %>%
           parse_number()
  Cashflow <- page %>% 
           html_nodes(xpath = '//div[contains(h4, "Cashflow:")]') %>% 
           html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% 
           parse_number()
  Spendings <- page %>% 
           html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="Spendings"]/a' ) %>% 
           html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% 
           parse_number()
   Return <- tryCatch({ 
         page %>% 
           html_nodes(xpath =
            '//*[@id="Return"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/h1') %>%
           html_text(trim = TRUE)},
            error = function(err) {
            message("xpath doesn't exist")
            return(NA)
            })

  return(tibble(YearlyRevenue, Cashflow, Spending, Return))            
           
}
```

Comment: there is no direct error. the missing item is just not scraped and thus makes a different length of the final vector. this then produces an error.
It should more be something like 
" If xpath = "...Return..." is not found, than return NA"

Comment: @TomTe  May be you can wrap the `tryCatch` around the second part i.e. for 'Return' and then construct `tibble` afterwards