# How to return NA for an xpath not found

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, rvest

I have a function scraping similar websites. Some of these sites DO NOT contain the xpath defined below. However, I sill need to have "NA" returned in that case of the missing xpath.

```
page <- read_html("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2620590/")

Budget_raw = page %>% 
           html_nodes(xpath = '//div[contains(h4, "Budget:")]') %>% replace((Budget_raw), NA) %>%
           html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% 
           parse_number()
```

Don't know how to get the replace function to work in this case.
Or would if else workaround work better?

Any ideas or other recommendation?!
Much appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a enough code to repro this? Also, did the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66520298/within-a-function-return-na-or-0-if-xpath-is-not-to-found) not help?

Comment: sorry, i forgot the URL. And no, so far, I wasnt able to solve this.

Comment: Do you have an url where budget is present? I think the answer is to use html_node which will return NA where not present

Comment: here is a budget figure present:

page <-  read_html("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0420294/")

Yes, i am exactly looking for NA or 0 as return vale if that nore is not available

Comment: `page %>% html_node(xpath = '//div[contains(h4, "Budget:")]') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% parse_number()`

Comment: this does not return NA, does it?

Comment: Yes. `read_html("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2620590/") %>% html_node(xpath = '//div[contains(h4, "Budget:")]') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% parse_number()
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229652/discussion-between-tomte-and-qharr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html_node` rather than `html_nodes` in your full code as you only want a single node match for each column within a given row. `html_node` will return N/A if match not found.

I've updated to use css where possible as quicker. Also, changed one of your xpaths so it returns the same gross (World) rather than US | World (as there were different child div counts you were mixing and matching gross figures)

Threw in a more straightforward extraction of `Titles` from a `script` tag as well as `list_name`.

Tidied up some naming.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

return_data <- function(url) {
  page <- url %>% read_html()
  tibble(
    Gross_raw = page %>%
      html_node(xpath = '//div[contains(h4, "Cumulative Worldwide Gross:")]') %>% # otherwise you are picking up different gross e.g. US v World
      html_text(trim = TRUE) %>%
      parse_number(),
    Budget_raw = page %>%
      html_node(xpath = '//div[contains(h4, "Budget:")]') %>%
      html_text(trim = TRUE) %>%
      parse_number(),
    Year = page %>%
      html_node("#titleYear a") %>%
      html_text(trim = TRUE) %>%
      parse_number(),
    Title = page %>%
      html_node(".title_wrapper h1") %>%
      html_text(trim = TRUE)
  )
}
   
start_url <- "https://www.imdb.com/list/ls020643534/?sort=list_order,asc&st_dt=&mode=detail&page=1&title_type=movie&ref_=ttls_ref_typ"
page <- read_html(httr::GET(start_url, add_headers("Accept-Language" = "en-US")))

json <- page %>%
  html_node('[type="application/ld+json"]') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  jsonlite::fromJSON()

list_name <- gsub(
  " Series| series| Series in Order| Franchise| Collection| FRANCHISE| Films| - In Order| -in Order| Film series| Film Series|Series - | franchise| Movies| Ranked| movies| Series! \\ '| Film Series'", "",
  gsub(" \\(.*?)", "", json$name)
)

film_url <- map(json$about$itemListElement$url, url_absolute, start_url) %>% unlist()
film_name <- page %>%
  html_nodes(".lister-item-header a") %>%
  html_text()

dataset <- data.frame(film_name, film_url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
result <- cbind(dataset, map_df(dataset$film_url, return_data))
print(result)
```

---

Also, had a look to see if could speed up with `furrr`, which indeed it did:

```
library(furrr)

no_cores <- future::availableCores() - 1
future::plan(future::multisession, workers = no_cores)
result <- cbind(dataset, future_map_dfr(film_url, .f = return_data))
```